# SSRS accessing class instance problem

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I recieve [error in class Instance declaration for class TestClass:[BC30002] type 'TestClass' is not defiend. I get this in VS2005 IDE
expression is =Code.M_TestClass.ReturnTheStr()
Reference Mytest dll,  CLASS TestClass INSTANCE M_Testclass

DLL Code

```
namespace MyTest
{
   public  class TestClass
    {
       public TestClass() : base()
       {
           // Constructo
       }
       public static string ReturnStr()
       {
           return "Help is here";
       }
       public string ReturnTheStr()
       {
           return "Instance Help is here";
       }
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When providing CLASS name under References needed to prifix with Namespace
Mytest.Testclass